# Change Anchor Link Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change an anchor link on a certain page using jQuery.

How can I change the anchors link to something like `#` or `javascript:void(0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change one link,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">One Link</a>

$('#link')[0].href = '#';
```

Plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('link').href = '#'
```

Changing multiple links,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="links">One Link</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="links">One Link</a>
<a href="http://www.hotmail.com" class="links">One Link</a>


$('a.links').each(function () {
   this.href = '#';
});
```

Comment: @user1658756 Try `document.getElementById('link').href = '#';` and see updated post

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="mylink">Link</a>

// JavaScript
$("a.mylink").prop("href", "#");
```

Comment: `.attr()` should be used for `href`. From [the jQuery 1.6.1 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/): "*The .prop() method should be used for boolean attributes/properties and for properties which do not exist in html (such as window.location).*"

Comment: @Eric From the technical point of view, `$("#smth").prop("href", "#")` in this context is the same as `document.getElementById("smth").href = "#"` which is fast and more than normal. I see no problems with it.